# App hanging on first AppStore download then always crashes on launch (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, crash-log

My app has been on the AppStore for two months now and I had no issues with it so far. Recently, after a fresh install from the AppStore the app hangs for an undetermined time and ends up crashing on only one of my devices (iPhone 6S Plus). I get crashes every time I try to launch the app afterwards. I tried to compile my current version on the phone and the one I have on TestFlight: no problems at all. I also tried with other devices (iPhone 5S, 6 & 6S) and I don't get this problem.

I've checked the crash logs on the phone and I get this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: WAKEUPS
Exception Message: (Limit 150/sec) Observed 434/sec over 300 secs
Exception Note:  NON-FATAL CONDITION (this is NOT a crash)
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Attributed:
0   UIKit                           0x0000000188c17d08 0x1887c0000 + 4553992
1   UIKit                           0x0000000188e97b94 0x1887c0000 + 7175060
2   UIKit                           0x0000000189063628 0x1887c0000 + 9057832
3   UIKit                           0x00000001887cf030 0x1887c0000 + 61488
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fd5f14 0x187fc8000 + 57108
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fd0b20 0x187fc8000 + 35616
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fd09e0 0x187fc8000 + 35296
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fd007c 0x187fc8000 + 32892
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fcfdd0 0x187fc8000 + 32208
9   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187fc94bc 0x187fc8000 + 5308
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183233c30 0x183158000 + 900144
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832319d4 0x183158000 + 891348
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183231e04 0x183158000 + 892420
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183160dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
14  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e2b4088 0x18e2a8000 + 49288
15  UIKit                           0x000000018883af44 0x1887c0000 + 503620
16  DogeApp                         0x0000000100118c30 0x1000bc000 + 379952
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019869e8b8 0x19869c000 + 10424
```

As well as this:

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000130dce590   x1: 0x00000001891c083e   x2: 0x0000000000000060   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x000000000000004e   x5: 0x000000000000005f   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000a00
    x8: 0x000000019e463000   x9: 0x000000019f15da18  x10: 0x0000000130808b50  x11: 0x000000100000001f
   x12: 0x0000000130808d30  x13: 0x000021a19f15da1d  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0001e0000001e000
   x16: 0x00000001891c083e  x17: 0x0000000188c17d08  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000012f624280
   x20: 0x000000012f910600  x21: 0x00000001891af2aa  x22: 0x0000000130dd3410  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0xf1001db01d6f42f0  x26: 0x000000016fd41938  x27: 0x0000000000000040
   x28: 0x0000000000000080  fp: 0x000000016fd41750   lr: 0x0000000188e97b94
    sp: 0x000000016fd41610   pc: 0x0000000188c17d08 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

[Full crash log here: [http://pastebin.com/ksVcHrLD]](http://pastebin.com/ksVcHrLD)

My first assumption was that I messed up something while transferring some data that I was storing in NSUserDefaults to the Keychain but after cleaning everything and trying several times I still get the same crash and only on this phone.

I still don't get it... I tried to reinstall a current version from XCode or TestFlight but the AppStore one keeps crashing on me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That crash log needs symbolicating as those numbers are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, okay. Just reboot the phone.